# Clear/Delete Chromium Embedded framework (CEF3 C++) cache

Tags: c++, caching, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am building a simple CEF3 based browser. I want the cache to be removed/deleted after the user closes/ends all the sessions. First I have tried to store the cache on the hard drive by using **Cefsettings.cache_path** but the folder is empty. 
Here is my code:

```
CefSettings settings;
  const char* path = "E:\\test\\Cefclient\\cache";
  //store cache on hdd
  CefString(&settings.cache_path).FromASCII(path);
```

The cache folder is empty, also this path: ***C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\CEF\User Data***, which was generated before I changed the path is empty. What could be the problem? And what method do I use to clear/delete this cache?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the cache path after you called CefShutDown,
you can also confirm you cache path by "chrome://version"
[image]

Comment: Thanks for attempting to contribute an answer. However it will be nice if you can explain more about the solution as the current one seems to be so naive.